# Can I use snap to install nextcloud on a server already running Apache?

Tags: apache2, proxypass, nextcloud

Nextcloud is an open source cloud data server.  On OS's with `snapd` you can install the whole thing as a snap:
 `sudo snap install nextcloud`

That seems magical, but I am stuck there. My server was already hosting various domains using Apache, and I do not even know where to look for the landing page of nextcloud. All the instructions / manuals I can find do not explain where the site is, or how the snap will interact with existing Apache.
 I now suspect I cannot use a snap if I already have Apache running? But this was not clear in what I read.

I have a separate IP domain for the nextcloud server, so I just need the snap to take care of requests for one domain-name.

Can I use snap to install nextcloud on a server already running Apache?

**Update**:

I have tried the following:

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
sudo snap set nextcloud ports.http=81
sudo snap restart nextcloud.apache
```

At that point I can see the nextcloud page exists with

```
links http://localhost:81
```

However, I cannot access it from another computer to continue the setup.  How do I proceed? 
(The hope at this point is that I can have the server's main/existing Apache2 server map port 81 and 443 to a virtual host of my chosen domain name).

**Update 2:**

One problem, above, was that the port 81 was blocked to the outside world.

Let's say that I have unused ports `9992` and `9993` visible to the Internet from my existing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server with IP address 111.222.333.444:
 and IP name `example.net`; and that this server is hosting various sites already using `Apache 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.13`; and that I have set up a new IP name `clouddomain.example.org` that points to the same IP addres as `example.net`.

I find that using a modern browser, even under incognito mode, and even using ctrl-shift-r to reload pages, does not reflect my latest changes as I make them (ie, is caching things). Therefore, I use `links` to test URLs in the procedure below.

I run

```
sudo snap install nextcloud
sudo nextcloud.manual-install myadmin mypassword
sudo snap set nextcloud ports.http=9992
```

At this point,

```
links http://example.net:9992
```

displays the nextcloud landing page.

I then set up an Apache .conf file with contents

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.333.444:80>
    ServerName   clouddomain.example.org
        ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/clouddomain.example.org_error_log
        CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/clouddomain.example.org_access_log combined
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9992/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9992/
</VirtualHost>
```

and I link it from sites-available to sites-enabled and I restart the OS's Apache server with one of:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Now

```
links http://clouddomain.example.org
```

gets me to the nextcloud page.
Calling

```
sudo nextcloud.occ config:system:set overwritehost --value="clouddomain.example.org"
```

makes no difference at this point.

Next, I need to get the site working with SSL (https). I cannot.
If I call

```
sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
```

and enter the appropriate information, I am told that a certificate has been issued and Apache restarted. However, this leaves nothing working. The non-SSL page is no longer available; it gives me a 503 error. 
The SSL page is also not available:

```
links https://clouddomain.example.org:9993
```

gives connection refused.
 There are no error events created for these efforts at `/var/snap/nextcloud/current/apache/logs/error_log`

Not surprisingly, creating the second proxy conf for the Apache2 server on example.net does not help, but here is what I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.333.444:80>
    ServerName   clouddomain.example.org
        ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/clouddomain.example.org_error_log
        CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/clouddomain.example.org_access_log combined
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9992/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9992/
</VirtualHost>
```

I've noticed another problem, which suggests to me that one of my issues might be idiosyncratic, though I don't think this is the only issue: when I activate the SSL proxy, my other sites, not at clouddomain.example.org but hosted by the sever example.net, fail to conect by https. This is true even without nextcloud installed.

Comment: i setup nextcloud with the php installer on a contAiner without sny issues. so i think this would be the more "safer" way at the point of View.

Comment: Configure a virtual host on your apache listening on port 80 and acting as a reverse proxy (forwarding every request to localhost:80) would be a solution.

Comment: @JohannesH: Yes, thanks.  I've already been trying that for countless hours. I've now specified in more detail where I get stuck.